# What's a simple way to slow down a loop?

Tags: java

I have an application which will call the function `autoIncrement();`, which I have a script in it like this:

```
public static void autoIncrement() {
    while(true) {
        varible++;
        // Wait 1,000 milliseconds.
    }
}
```

I've looked around a bunch and tried `Thread.sleep(1000);`, `wait(1000);`, and a bunch of custom definitions for these, but whenever I run the `autoIncrement();` function, the GUI I've made crashes, no matter *what* I use.

Does anyone know why this is happening and any script that may help me [wait 1 second] in my code?

Comment: what is the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Have you tried a synchronized method?

Comment: If you are running a wait/sleep on the main thread, the UI will freeze momentarily every time (the UI thread handles the actual interface, and if it is paused, the UI will pause). Assuming UI freezing is your issue, then introducing multithreading will solve the problem. However, what is the use-case for pausing the thread? Is it truly needed?

Comment: Note per the suggestions in answers that in `Thread.sleep(1000);` the sleep itself _can_ be interrupted, so there is the possibility that "sleep 1000ms" actually sleeps for only 1ms. To guarantee the sleep time you have to catch `InterruptedException` and sleep again (for a shorter time) if your desired sleep time hasn't elapsed yet.  There's also [TimeUnit.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep-long-) but it also throws InterruptedException.

Comment: @drum - It doesn't output anything, it just freezes, and Windows still treats it as a responding program. Yet the close buttons on the window don't work, and the GUI is completely unresponsive.

Comment: As has already been mentioned if you sleep on the main UI thread the UI will hang - as you are getting. You need to tell us which GUI framework you are using (SWT, JavaFX, Swing/AWT, ....) as the answer depends on that.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep(1000);` is the right way to wait 1 second.

However, if `autoIncrement` is called in the so-called 'EDT' (Event Dispatch Thread), that's no good; you must never block (= have the thread 'freeze', which happens on explicit calls to sleep, but also any attempt to access disk or network resources or a DB) in the EDT, because if you do, the OS thinks you have crashed. You're in the EDT whenever an event handler is called (for example, the code you register as a click listener).

It is simply not possible to wait 1 second in the EDT, therefore, it is not possible to wait 1 second here. At all.

But what you can do, is start another thread and let THAT wait one second, and then inject a job to for example increment the variable back into the EDT if that is needed, or just do it itself (note that from outside the EDT you cannot/should not mess with any GUI element).

To inject code into the EDT to run, it's `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { code goes here })`. To start threads, check the threading tutorial, or, use `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Hmm that sounds like it could work, I'm very new to Java so is there anything else I should need to try and make this work?

Comment: Nope, what I described is the way - hence why I explained the _why_.